# Grouping and Summing Multiple Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a large dataset that is similar in structure to this:

[image]

I am trying to get an ouput that groups and sums by customer and metal like this:

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this in Pandas without having to iterate over rows?  This difference I have here between this and other groupby() sum() questions is that in this case I am not trying to sum a single column, but multiple columns.

Comment: Grouping and then taking the first value of account and the sum of all others should do this:
`grouped = df.groupby(["Metal", "Customer"])`
`pd.merge(grouped["Acct"].first(), grouped.sum(), left_index=True, right_index=True)`

Comment: Once I got this suggestion working it seemed to completely drop the metal and customer columns after the merge.  I did alter it to be ```df=pd.merge(grouped["Acct"].first(), grouped.sum(), left_index=True, right_index=True)```

Comment: They are now the index.  If you add in `df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)` then they will become columns again.